# Metasploit Closing Connections?

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, metasploit

Whenever I attempt to use an exploit (that I know will work) from Metasploit in Windows on a machine on my LAN, I always get the error

```
    Exploit exception: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

I do not know why this is happening as my firewall is off and anitvirus is disabled. How reliable is this message; is it actually caused because a connection is being aborted or is this just a sign of a more generic problem? Thanks.

Comment: Operating system? I assume Windows?

Comment: cli or console? Can you give us the exploit config?

Comment: when you say 'local machine' are you trying to exploit yourself?

Comment: Operating system is windows; local machine as in a machine on my LAN; and I'm using console, as an exploit example I was trying out the Rhinosoft Serv-u FTP Web Client Buffer Overflow and it gives me this error, as does IIS 5.0 webdav exploit.

Comment: Is something else using your listener port? Have you tried alternate ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first look, and without more data, I would still say that you have a local firewall/AV issue.

Run wireshark or tcpdump to see how far the connection gets before it gets aborted.

EDIT

OR, you might have something running on your listener port.

Comment: Yeah I'll run tcpdump and see what I get.